# Only keep shadow at the bottom of the view

Tags: android, angular-material, shadow, android-elevation

have this layout -

```
<Stepsview
android:background="@color/white"
android:elevation="@dimen/margin_16"/>
```

this cast shadow at the bottom as well as top :
[image: Shadow effect at top and bottom of Steps views ( below actionbar )]

and what i need is :
[image: shadow effect only at the bottom of steps]

Steps view and ActionBar are 2 different views, one way I see is to combine these 2 views inside a view group and set elevation on the view group only.
Is there any other way only controlling steps view.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it by dynamically adding the steps to the top abbbar ( container for toolbar )  and setting the elevation to the app bar itself.